# GoogleDriveAPI AppProperties update

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

My goal is to replace an existing `AppProperties` dictionary containing 8 values entirely with one that has only 6. My understanding was that this method would accomplish this, however the returned `rsp.AppProperties` still has 8 keys after the update. Is this a feature or a bug and what do I have to do for these to wind up in sync?

```cs
using Metadata = Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File;

static partial class Extensions
{
    private static async Task<Metadata> UpdateProperties(
        this string id, 
        IDictionary<string, string> appProperties)
    {
        var reqUpdate =
            DriveService
            .Files
            .Update(new Metadata
            {
                AppProperties = appProperties,
            }, id);
        reqUpdate.Fields = DefaultFields;
        if (await reqUpdate.ExecuteAsync() is Metadata rsp)
        {
#if DEBUG
            Debug.Assert(
                rsp.AppProperties.Count == appProperties.Count,
                "Expecting the AppProperties has bee replaced and has the same count");
#endif
            return rsp;
        }
        else return default;
    }
}
```